# Element to use where a taller toolbar is needed (Google maps style with 2 textfields)

Tags: iphone

I am wondering what element can be used where the usual 44px won't do. There doesn't seem to be an obvious option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass a UIView and make it 88-px high, make your own graphics, etc.